# Assign Weights to Each Colour

Tags: sql

So I have columns of data that should correspond to Red, Yellow or Green. With Green being the highest attainable and yellow being in the middle and red being the lowest.

What I have written below checks if the sum of these columns are zero. If so, then it is assigned N/A and so on.

If there are more Greens than red AND more greens than yellow's, it is assigned as Excellent. However, this is the wrong logic because if there are duplicates such as 3 greens and 3 reds, then my overall output would correspond to a green when it should be yellow.

```
IF SUM([# of Yellow])=0 and SUM([# of Green])=0 and SUM([# of Red])=0 THEN
    "N/A"
elseif SUM([# of Green])> SUM([# of Red]) and SUM([# of Green])> SUM([# of Yellow]) THEN
   "Excellent"
elseif SUM([# of Red])> SUM([# of Green]) and SUM([# of Red])> SUM([# of Yellow]) THEN
   "Poor"
ELSE
    "Fair" 
End
```

In addition, if I wanted to assign a value say 1 to Green and 3 to Yellow or 5 to Red, and to whichever has the highest score, that colour would dominate. How do I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use algorithm

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM([# of Yellow])=0 and SUM([# of Green])=0 and SUM([# of Red])=0 THEN  'N/A'
        WHEN ( ( SUM([# of Green]) > SUM([# of Red]) )
                OR  ( SUM([# of Green]) = SUM([# of Red]) AND SUM([# of Green]) > SUM([# of Yellow]) ) ) THEN 'Excellent'
        WHEN ( ( SUM([# of Red]) > SUM([# of Green]) )
                OR  ( SUM([# of Red]) = SUM([# of Green]) AND SUM([# of Red]) > SUM([# of Yellow]) ) ) THEN 'Poor'
        ELSE 'Fair'
    End
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL subquery

```
SELECT IF Y=0 and G=0 and R=0 THEN
    "N/A"
elseif G> R and G> Y THEN
   "Excellent"
elseif R> G and R> Y THEN
   "Poor"
ELSE
    "Fair" 
End
FROM
(
     SELECT Y = SUM([# of Yellow]), G = SUM([# of Green]), R = SUM([# of Red]) FROM ...
) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested case statement.  I've attached an example temp table for reference. The case statement first checks if the sum values are 0.  Next, if `(Green > Yellow) AND (Green > Red)` it gives the weight Green.  Similar logic is used for Red. The last possibility is Yellow by default, and code for this is actually not required other than `ELSE 'Yellow'`

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Red int, Yellow int, Green int)
INSERT INTO @temp 
VALUES (0, 0, 0)
     , (2, 1, 1)
     , (2, 2, 2)
     , (1, 2, 3)
     , (1, 3, 2)
     , (3, 0, 3)

SELECT CASE WHEN Green + Yellow + Red = 0 
             THEN 'N/A'
             ELSE CASE WHEN (Green > Yellow) AND (Green > Red)
                        THEN 'Green'
                        ELSE CASE WHEN (Red > Green) AND (Red > Yellow)
                                   THEN 'Red'
                                   ELSE 'Yellow'
                              END
                  END
       END AS [Weight]
  FROM @temp
```

Comment: How would that be written in Tableau?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.